# Distribution table for number of white balls without replacement

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

I have a box with $4$ white and $2$ black balls. I want to find the random variable distribution table for the number of white balls when I take $3$ balls without replacement. Now if we had replacement, I believe the answer would be the binomial distribution, but without replacement I have no idea. I suspect the answer is the same, but I'm not certain. Any help is welcomed.

Comment: Clearly not the same.  With replacement you can have $0$ white balls, without replacement you can not.  Just go case by case...one white?  So you need $BBW,BWB,WBB$.  Either compute all three or convince yourself that they are equally likely.  Two whites...

Comment: @lulu Thanks :)

Comment: Without replacement this is the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) but it might be easier to calculate by hand here

Answer (score 1):

Here is the distribution from R software.

```
 pdf = dhyper(x, 4, 2, 3)
 cbind(x, pdf)
     x pdf
     0 0.0
     1 0.2
     2 0.6
     3 0.2
```

Here $P(X = x)$ is the probability of getting
exactly $X$ white balls when three balls are
drawn without replacement from the box.

Obviously,
it is impossible to get no white balls, because
there are only two non-white balls in the box.
So $P(X = 0) = 0$ is the first entry in the PDF table.

Now your job is to express each of these probabilities
in terms of binomial coefficients according to the
formula for the hypergeometric PDF (also called PMF) in your textbook or in @Henry's link to Wikipedia; each is a fraction
with ${6 \choose 3}$ in the denominator.